# Do employers expect a ultimate career goal in career objective?

Tags: career-development, resume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I include a career objective on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-i-include-a-career-objective-on-my-resume)

There is a field, career objective, in CV which is confusing to me.

I am certain that employers do not want some vague statement, instead, they might expect a possible job title. For example: "To gain the position of Analyst Programmer...". I googled to confirm this.

However I am not sure if I need to write my next possible level (e.g. Analyst Programmer) or the highest possible position (e.g.: IT manager).

There is a huge difference between people who only seek to become of a coder and a people who would have the ambition to manage people (and not code anymore).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi gunbuster363, your question has been closed as a duplicate.  If you think they are truly different, please feel free to edit the question to make those differences clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frankly, do not waste valuable resume space on a career objective. That will not ever help you get hired and a badly written or inappropriate one will get your resume kicked out of the pile. For instance, we never interviewed the guy who said he wanted to work for the CIA even though his qualifications for our job looked good. That was because we weren't the CIA and he clearly wasn't interested in working at our company.

You are far better served putting your accomplishments on your resume than a career objective.

Comment: Heh, I remember you mentioning the CIA guy in a comment and wondering how awesome it'd be if you were working at the FSB at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Your career objective should not be a job title, but a very short description of what you are hoping for from your career, in the relative short term. This [article](http://eduworldinfo.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/writing-a-good-career-objective-in-your-cv/) has some good points:

> - Keep the English simple
> - Keep the sentences short, precise and concise. Cut the verbiage.
> - The tone of your Career Objective should be formal.
> - The Grammar should be correct.
> - Check your spelling more than a few times.
> - Do not copy and paste other peoples Career Objectives
> - It is best to keep your Career Objectives 3-4 lines.
> - Make sure your Career Objectives match the job you are applying for.  A line like this > - “Looking for vacancy as a fresher, in business process outsourcing, human resource development and as an article writer for a leading newspaper” is a big NO NO!

and some good examples:

> “To secure a promising position that offers both a challenge and a good opportunity for growth”.
>
> “To work in association with professional groups who offer me the opportunity for career advancement and professional growth.”
>
> “To work in a stimulating environment where I can apply & enhance my knowledge, skill to serve the firm to the best of my efforts.”

Comment: The examples are quite vague. They didn't even give the type of work and are demanding any possible position.

Comment: @gunbuster363 Well, that's what a career objective is, you are not supposed to demand a position.

Comment: I just read an website here stating that the content should be solid. http://www.sci.monash.edu.au/undergrad/employ/objective.html

Comment: @gunbuster363 I think that website is a bit misleading, the examples do mention job roles, but the guidelines say that you should describe the nature of the work you want to do. Sometimes the job role _may_ help describe the nature of the work, but not everytime. I'd stick with a general description of the work and avoid a job title, it seems a bit pompous.

Comment: The examples presented as good are far too vague. They're effectively meaningless. Those are objectives that everyone has. The career objective, if you have one, should describe some specific job functions and relatively short term aspirations that are understandable by the employer. The advice in the link is horribly out-of-date.

Comment: The three good examples - who wouldn't?  I prefer less generic things like 'develop my skills in technology X and in leading small groups on quick projects" (or something similar) that is less generic and something where not everyone will want the same things.  Try and be a little original (just not too wacky) to stand out in that pile of resumes.

Comment: Also tailor it to the industry and career.  Management positions require softer skills, hand-on positions, les so, etc.