# Is it useful to split a CV into a HR section and Tech team section?

Tags: software-industry, resume, human-resources, manager, applications

Since the HR team looks for cursory information (role name, years of experience, gap in CV and technology names like C++ or Java) to filter out CV's and since the Tech managers or tech leads would look for a different set of info (how the candidate used the tech and how relevant it is for the current job). I considered dividing my CV into two sections:

**Info for the HR team:**
Tech I worked with: C++ (5 years), Python (4 years), AWS (4 years).
Most recent role: Tech lead at XYZ company (4 years).
Education: MTech in ML from ABC university (2010). CGPA: 8.8.

**Info for the Tech team:**
Here info is listed out in the usual format available in any CV.

Would such a format help companies and help my CV's chances of getting shortlisted? If yes, what content would you suggest for each section?

Comment: No one is going to read a CV twice, and that's what you are creating there

Comment: The idea is to provide a summary of relevant info that's quicker to read.

Comment: I think it's fine to put a summary of skills near the top (essentially the first line of your `Info for the HR Team`, but I wouldn't bother listing out positions that you're then going to repeat in the next section, in more detail. Also I wouldn't label the summary `Info for the HR team` as some HR teams will look for more than "cursory information"

Comment: Most HR will anyway use an automatic parser that extracts the information from your CV into whatever system they use, so they will be looking for this information in their system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, don't deviate from the standard resume layout.

Resumes follow a pretty fixed format and deviating from that format is rarely helpful and usually makes it harder for people to parse. Remember, HR recruiters are used to dealing with these resumes. They're perfectly capable of scanning your resume to identify the essentials they're after. Most resumes are reviewed in seconds, not minutes and if you're going "off script" that doesn't help much. You're either placing info where it's not expected or repeating things. And you should stick to one or two pages. ([Why is a one to two page résumé recommended?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/844/why-is-a-one-to-two-page-r%c3%a9sum%c3%a9-recommended)) There's also a subtext here that says "here's the non-technical stuff for you numpties" that could rub some people the wrong way.

Generally speaking, any tips or advice on "standing out" with your resume are bad because you're trying to get noticed **for the wrong reasons**. A good resume and cover letter stand out by being succinct, showing relevant skills and a good experience match, and speaking convincingly on your value as a potential hire. That's all you need. Focus on that content and not the form.

HR will scan a resume for employment history and dates so that structure **needs** to be there and ideally in the expected place. If those match they'll also read your summary<sup>1</sup> which you should always include these days. That summary should be short and to the point and describe you professionally in just a few sentences. It is *not* a rehash of dates and positions!

After reading that they might scan a skill section or particulars of your work experience for matching keywords. Many HR recruiters, though certainly not all, are also more than familiar with the tech lingo than you might expect as they often hire for technical roles repeatedly.

The technical team, specifically your hiring manager will go into more detail but even they will want to see a traditional resume layout because they'll be wanting to check the same things as the HR recruiter will! They also want to get a sense of your overall experience and see if you've worked anywhere familiar.

[This guide](https://www.askamanager.org/2020/02/my-step-by-step-guide-to-writing-a-resume.html) from Ask a Manager is a good start on resume structure. You can also take a look at questions like [Is it a good idea to put Summary in place of Objective in your resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10477/is-it-a-good-idea-to-put-summary-in-place-of-objective-in-your-resume?rq=1) for more.

So, long story short, stick with what works.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>A summary, never an objective! - [Should I include a career objective on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-i-include-a-career-objective-on-my-resume)</sub>