# Where to put planned master's degree on resume

Tags: resume

I am a senior studying computer science, but I am going to a career fair looking for an internship, not a full time job, since I am planning to pursue a master's degree in the computer science next year. Where do I put this planned master's degree in my resume to let employers know why I am looking for an internship and not a full-time job?

Comment: If you have not started it, it shouldn't be on your resume, because in 6 months your plans might change.  If you have started it, while your plans can change, at least you have made progress.  If you are looking for a internship apply to those jobs, don't apply, to full time jobs.

Answer (score 3):

Preferably the cover letter, or the "Objectives" section of your resume.  Be sure to explain that you are looking for an internship and not a full time job.

At a college career fair, most of the recruiters/companies will likely be very understanding of your situation, so when you meet face-to-face at the career fair, be sure to explain this as you hand them your resume.

Comment: +1 for cover letters - resumes are for listing what you have done, cover letters are where you put your intentions/objectives

Comment: You have tripped my Objectives sensor. [Do not include such a section on your resume.](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-i-include-a-career-objective-on-my-resume)

Comment: In general I agree with not including an objectives.  In this case though, the objective is non-obvious (most graduates will be looking for full time jobs), and I can't remember EVER handing a cover letter out at a campus job fair.