# I sent the wrong resume?

Tags: resume, applications, email

I sent a resume to Google but I forgot to change the company name from my previous application in the objective. I want to send the correct resume but I have no idea where to send it ? The email confirmation I got for the application was from a "no-reply" email. Does anyone know what the HR email is ? Have I blown my chance ?

Comment: How did you send it the first time? The first part of your post starts with "I sent a resume to Google" which would imply you did send one once.

Comment: I filled out a regular online application on their website specifically for the position. It had a "upload resume" button to which I uploaded the wrong resume.

Comment: Does that have a profile where you could update the resume? If not, could you consider re-applying and putting a note somewhere that you had submitted the wrong resume?

Comment: They have a profile but no place to update resume. There is a wait time of 90 days to apply again for the same position....

Comment: Then you wait 3 months and try again. There is an entire branch of Google that sells HR Services that you could contact: https://www.google.ca/work/hr.html

Comment: [**Never include an Objective(s) section in your resume.**](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/173/25739) Your resume is an overview of your skills and experience and you "sell yourself" in the cover letter.

Answer (score 3):

So you blew it. No big deal.

Take this as a lesson-learned. For better results, your resume should be tailored to the specific company you're targeting, which means a different resume for every company.

### About 'Objectives'

What would be a 3-year objective? Consider putting **that** in your objectives section, instead of something like "My objective is to get a job with Acme, Inc. My other objective is to get paid every payday."

Comment: Agreed. If you are including an objective (which not everyone says you should), it shouldn't include the name of the company to which you are applying. Cover letters are a different story though and should certainly be directed at each company.

Comment: There's also a non-zero chance that no one will even notice..