# Is the objective in my resume/CV clear and correct?

Tags: resume, job-search

The following is what I have written for my OBJECTIVE in my resume:

> My aim is to get the position of receptionist of the restaurant,
>    during the night shift, to greet your guests, and treat every and each
>    of them with distinguished hospitality, to satisfy and assert the
>    relationship and confidence with the clientele

I want to know if there are any errors in what I have said above, particularly on the part where I wrote "during the night shift". I included that part in because I am looking to work part time on another restaurant, in another shift.

Comment: Objectives are out of style in resumes, and this question may get flagged as off-topic.

Comment: Whether or not people tend to write "Objective" or NOT doesn't quite define whether we should be allowed to ask a question. I don't see any reason this question should be closed!

Comment: Things go out of fashion - and come back to fashion. If writing objectives comes back to fashion in future, will you bring back this question and upvote it? It is ridiculous that we judge a genuine question because you wouldn't have done that in your resume.

Comment: One error: *recepcionist* should be *receptionist*.

Comment: @DipanMehta The issue here is not whether "Objective" is out of fashion because that is ... subjective. The issue is that the question is essentially asking for proof-reading a resume, which we do not do over here. The question of whether her part-time availability status should be mentioned in the resume, and if so, how to best describe it, should be ok though. I will try to make an edit when I am back home, but feel free to do it if you have some time. :)

Comment: One more error: *position*

Comment: An "objective" section in your resume (which is entirely optional) should only broadly explain what you're looking for in a role, not focus on the specifics of any given role. What you wrote there would be more appropriate for a cover letter, but even then you mostly just described the responsibilities of the role in a neutral manner - simply applying for the role implies that you understand the responsibilities, what you should be doing on your cover letter is expressing excitement over said responsibilities and/or the company itself.

Comment: Leave the "I can only work night shift" for when you actually talk to someone. A resume and cover letter are primarily about getting the employer interested, not about discussing the constraints of your employment.

Comment: I thought Objectives went the way of the dodo bird a long time ago. Your objective should be obvious; to get hired for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **cover letter** instead of an objective statement. It lets you explain your strengths and how can they help a company to achieve their goals in detail (*Source:* [Wozber Guidebook](https://www.wozber.com/us/guidebook/exclude-the-objective-and-summary-statements-from-your-resume/)).

An objective section doesn't have such a power because it's simply too short.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, many people have started saying "Objectives" are not out of fashion partly because too many people began writing many "useless and vague" objectives and it started looking like a copy paste job. I say this from my experience of being a recruiter and going through 100+ resume before filling up a position. I wrote about this in my [answer here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/318/143) so not elaborating job.

In brief, the objective should be crisp qualifier to see if you will be willing to take a job under question. If I see your resume, I find you are fit but if you yourself are not willing to take up that work; it is futile to shortlist you as a candidate. If you have been a project manager, it is likely to see you qualified for another such job. But if I say, I want to do "something else..." tells me not to invite you for jobs which you are not going to like.

Alternatively many people have multiple industry experience at various different positions - and after looking at the resume I would rather ask "So what do you want to now?" is a very natural question. And *that* question is what objective should answer - because none of your past can answer that!

Now, coming to your question,

I think you have done a pretty good job at identifying few specifics: you want to work
* at a "restaurant"  (do you prefer not to work anywhere else?) 
* as a receptionist  (qualifies you well as other works..)
* work in night shift.

Now like many resume *"...to greet your guests, and treat every and each of them with distinguished hospitality, to satisfy and assert the relationship and confidence with the clientele"* ... is not BAD but generally useless. If you are a restaurant receptionist, you better do that. In fact this kind of language is used by almost every one which gives 'objectives' as a bad name.

So in essence you can briefly outline in not more than 5-7 words what makes you think you make a good choice, or why you want to do this.

Regarding your question on "should we mention night shift". If this is a special constraint (and not a preference) you invest a full statement for it instead of mixing it between other long sentence.

for example: *"Want to work as a receptionist at restaurant (or 'generic' term) using my past experience (or any other reason). I am requiring to work on Night shift as due to my reason X"*.

Constraints that you make you look for a specific job is always respected by recruiter. And is important to mention. For example a mother of a new born who is fully qualified to do desk job or field jobs, but she wants to work from home, she should mention this. If you can work only in specific city, times, or need any other aspects make sense to list down. And it should be said without getting messed up in "type of role".

However, if work-from-home, working-only-in-the-specific-shift are a mere preference than it is not objective. Any factor that you don't want to be the reason for being disqualified upfront by a recruiter is not objective. Ask, if a recruiter who is willing to give you a "day-shift" job should give you a call or not?

Objectives should serve very critical purpose and perhaps, in my view, the most important thing it tell about the candidate irrespective of its past experience and her talent. Specifically, it tells you,

- What type of role you are looking for (hence, wether you want to do what recruiter has in stock),
- What ambition does one have (are you just another hopper or are you looking this as a step up in your profile, or are you actually desparate)
- How much a person is clear and self introspecting (people who are confused what job they want, will be pretty bad at making decisions!)

Comment: First of all, i preciate the time you took for this specific answer.

Comment: then, I would definetely extract this "objective" and design a cover letter for each job opportunity applying for the same role, highlighting on it my strenghts as duties... 
And, due to the shift, I'll leave the preference to the employer, cause it is more a specification for the postulation rather my mere preference.
Thanks, and It is very useful information @ https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-i-include-a-career-objective-on-my-resume/318#318

Comment: If people have a problem with question or answer, I am open to criticism. But If you down-vote, do explain what makes you frown upon that question or answer. Plain simple down votes without any reason is plain enmity than any criticism. 
It is a very bad cultural in workplace which I rarely see in other stack-exchange site.